# How to connect hibernate with IBM Db2 ODBC database, is it possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, odbc

Actually, I must connect my application to an IBM Db2 database where I'll have to read and write data. However, I can't change Java for another langage that would connect to an ODBC connection easly.

I saw that a possible bridge between JDBC and ODBC could be used, but I can't install new drivers, and so on, on my dev environment.

Maybe it exists an easy solution to connect it to hibernate ? But the documentations on internet are realy low.

(I'm using java 8, with springboot 2.7.5)

Comment: Use the db2jcc4.jar driver (jdbc driver) to allow hibernate to communicate with Db2. This combination is well known. It's possible to have a zero-install version of the IBM supplied jdbc driver, if you do not already have that driver on your development environment.  __BUT__ you need to know which Db2-server flavour is your target , Z/OS, i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud, because only the first two Z/OS and i-series require an additional client-side license (unless server-side licensing is enabled).

Comment: @mao there is no license requirement for JDBC to IBM i via the [JTOpen aka jt400](https://github.com/IBM/JTOpen) driver